# How to adjust the width of the Bootstrap progress bar and fully utilize the bar?

Tags: php, bootstrap-4

I'm making a quiz that have 18 questions. I want to add a progress bar using Bootstrap. I'm trying to change the width of the class progress-bar to much longer because I want it to be fully utilize the bar but I still can't find the solution.

```js
function getProgress() {
return document.getElementById("progressbar").getAttribute("aria-valuenow");
    
return document.getElementById("progressbar").getAttribute("style","width");
return document.getElementById("progressbar").innerHTML;
}

function setProgress(value) {
document.getElementById("progressbar").setAttribute("aria-valuenow",value);

document.getElementById("progressbar").setAttribute("style","width: " +value+ "%"); 
document.getElementById("progressbar").innerHTML = (value+ "%"); 
}

function increment() {
    var i = getProgress();
    if(i < 18){
        i++;
        setProgress(i); 
    }else{
        alert("Progress Complete!");
    }
}

function decrement() {
    var d = getProgress();
    setProgress(d - 1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="progress">
<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="1" aria-valuemax="18" id="progressbar" ></div>
</div>

<input type="button" value="Next" onclick = "increment()"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are only 18 questions, at some point, you should be dividing the number of questions answered by 18 and multiplying that value by 100 to get the percentage width you’re looking for, so something like this:

```js
function getProgress() {
    return document.getElementById("progressbar").getAttribute("aria-valuenow");

    /*return document.getElementById("progressbar").getAttribute("style", "width");
    return document.getElementById("progressbar").innerHTML;*/
}

function setProgress(value) {
    var percent = value / 18 * 100;
    document.getElementById("progressbar").setAttribute("aria-valuenow", value);

    document.getElementById("progressbar").setAttribute("style", "width: " + percent + "%");
    document.getElementById("progressbar").innerHTML = (value);
}

function increment() {
    var i = getProgress();
    if (i < 18) {
        i++;
        setProgress(i);
    }
    
    if (i === 18) {
        alert("Progress Complete!");
    }
}

function decrement() {
    var d = getProgress();
    setProgress(d - 1);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="1" aria-valuemax="18" id="progressbar"></div>
</div>

<div class="progress"></div>
<input type="button" value="Next" onclick="increment()" />
```

And only the return statement in your first function gets acted upon. Your other return statements don’t happen.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I really appreciate.